# Why Photon.Engine character animations do not appear on the other screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
public class PlayerSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] playerPrefabs;
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    private void Start()
    {
        int randomNuber=Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);  
        Transform spawnPoint=spawnPoints[randomNuber];
        GameObject playerToSpawn = playerPrefabs[(int)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Avatar"]];
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerToSpawn.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

///

I am developing a project with Photon Engine.
There is an error in my project.
The other player appears on the screen of the person with the MasterClient, but the MasterClient player is not visible on the screen of the other player.
This is not resolved even though I added a photon view.
Another error is that the character animations do not appear in the other player. I couldn't find out why.
Please help. I really need this.

Comment: Make sure to use `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate` when spawning.  This will create a copy on each connected client.

Comment: I added the code I wrote to my question. Could you please review it?

Comment: Have you tested each player as the master client?  Let the unity editor client be the non-master client, and check if the other clients objects appears in the hierarchy.  It may be disabled, or might be covered by the other player, since both can spawn at the same spawn point.  Code looks fine.  Check that the prefab asset names match the GameObjects name, since that is how you are instantiating the player prefabs.